# error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 with paramsquery

Tags: react-native

Using an api of live server but while testing in api in postman it uses query param but how to use in react native to call the api

```
 let response = await fetch(URI + '/staging-somewebsite.com/index.php?route=webservices/api&method=appRegisterUser', {
                          method: 'POST',
                          headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                          },
                          Params:{
                            'route': 'webservices/api',
                            'method': 'appRegisterUser',
                          },
                          body: JSON.stringify({

                              firstname: this.state.firstname,
                              lastname: this.state.lastname,
                              email: this.state.email,
                              mobile_number: this.state.mobile_number,
                              password: this.state.password,

                          })
                        });
```

Comment: Check the request and the response in the browser console. It looks like the API is responding with HTML or XML instead of JSON, which may denote an error.

Comment: the response is in json but how to manage with the params query in postman it runs while i am using it with params query and same in url

Comment: Are you sure the parameters go both in the URL *and* in the `Params` field?

Comment: yes in postman it works like this only  its an third party api so in url and param field it requires ? i am stuck can u help?

Comment: This is my last idea, if it doesn't work I'm not sure I can help further: have you tried `params` instead of `Params`? To be fair, looking at the `fetch` API documentation, `params` doesn't seem to exist as a parameter to `fetch`. Also it would help to know what kind of response the server is sending. A 400? 405?